# Ensure correct version of dll is used with application

Tags: c#, dll, version, .net-assembly

I have 2 .Net applications and a dll as part of my project. How do I ensure that the user of the application is utilising the correct version of the dll?

Answer (score 0):

Put a function call in the dll, which I assume is c or c++ and call it.

Comment: My dll is .Net also. Sorry forgot to add that detail in my question